# Android Layout not loading as expected in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have created a layout for a fragment which seems to be looking fine in portrait mode but in landscape I am not able to see the layout properly and scrolling seems to be not working.

Find below fragment_layout.xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.fragments.TestFragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/background">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/randomMainRelLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ranNWImage1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ranNWImageView1"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ranNWImageTxtView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ranNWImageView1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ranNWImageView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ranNWImageView1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ranNWImageView1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Image Heading"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="18dip"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ranNWImage2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranNWImage1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ranNWImageView2"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ranNWImageTxtView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ranNWImageView2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ranNWImageView2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ranNWImageView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ranNWImageView2"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Image Heading"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="18dip"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/randomHeading"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/randomMainRelLayout"
    android:text="THIRD HEADING"
    android:textColor="@color/title"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/secondMainRelLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/randomHeading"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relNWImage1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/relNWImageView1"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/relNWImageTxtView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relNWImageView1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relNWImageView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relNWImageView1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relNWImageView1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Image Heading"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="18dip"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relNWImage2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relNWImage1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/relNWImageView2"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/relNWImageTxtView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relNWImageView2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relNWImageView2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relNWImageView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relNWImageView2"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Image Heading"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="18dip"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondHeading"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/secondMainRelLayout"
    android:text="second"
    android:textColor="@color/title"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/firstMainRelLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/secondHeading"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstNWImageView"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/firstTitleRelLayout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstNWImageView"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first__heading"
            android:text="FIRST HEADING"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first__title"
            android:text="Subtitle"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout looks like as below image:

[image: Fragment Layout in Portrait mode]

Its messing up in landscape mode. Not sure what I am missing? Any help will be appreciated.

It looks as below in landscape. The layout is fixed, no scrolling;

[image: Landscape mode]

Comment: What kind of mess? How does it show in landscape mode?

Comment: What do you define by "properly"? Because it will always be shown has you defined.

Comment: @JuanAguilarGuisado added screenshot

Comment: @PedroOliveira By properly I meant, the layout doesn't seem to rendering as it is doing in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have a ScrollView element so it won't scroll.

It seems that it's drawn properly as per your xml, as you defined the bottom elements first in your xml - the landscape screen isn't tall enough to display everything, so the other elements do not get displayed. Is this your intent to start drawing the third element, docking it to the bottom? It seems that your layout should just be a simple stacking of elements from top to botton, all of it inside a ScrollView? Without you explaining the intent of what you want to achieve, it's difficult to say.

Comment: You are right. I am just stacking all the elements on top of each other but not inside any ScrollView. I will be setting the imageview src and  update the textview text via a fragment. Its strange when I swipe up in portrait mode, I don't see any dragging effect at the bottom.

Comment: Tried wrapping a scrollview but got error: Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: Fixed it by wrapping linear layout inside a scrollview. Thanks for your help.